# is "referrerpolicy" a valid attribute of <a>?

Tags: referrer, referrer-policy

Ok 'cause I was seeing on W3Schools and it enlists on the "Attributes" table of `<a>` element the referrerpolicy attribute. So I want to know if this is possible and how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like W3C says :

> The Referrer-Policy HTTP header governs which referrer information,
>   sent in the Referer header, should be included with requests made.

That mean that you can configure if the target website will have access to the `referrer` information.

For example: Use `<a href="http://example.com" referrerpolicy="origin">` to only give access to the `origin` information to the target.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy